# If all the Trappist-1 planets are tidally locked, which ones may have temperate zones?

Tags: exoplanet, tidal-locking, trappist-1, climate

Since all the Trappist-1 planets have circular orbits, it is [entirely likely that all them are tidally locked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRAPPIST-1#Tidal_locking).

If so, which ones of the planets may have temperate zones either on the bright or dark sides?

Comment: Different but related to this unique and resonant system: [Just how “locked” are resonant-chains of exoplanets thought to be? (e.g. K2-138 and TOI-178)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/23980/7982) and [Are the planets in the TRAPPIST-1 system so close that inhabitants on one planet could see surface details on the other planets?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33178/7982) and [How many things are wrong in this “artist view” of the TRAPPIST-1 system?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/20200/7982) Those are about orbital resonance, but this is about *tidal locking*.